# Windows Servers on ESXi 100% CPU at year rollover

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi, cpu-usage

We have a number of Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 servers running on ESXi servers. At year end rollover 2014 to 2015 the CPUs go to 100% and the machines hang.

The solution appears to be a hotfix (KB2800231) from Microsoft. However, the only listed downloads are all for Vista (Windows 6.0) and our servers are 6.1. Needless to say, when trying to run the MSU it errors saying that we have an unsupported operating system.

The hotfix web page (http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2800213/en-us) indicates that there should be downloads for 2008 R2, but it is not clear.

Does anyone know of a later fix for this problem, or where the correct MSU can be downloaded?

Comment: Do you have vmtools installed to your guests?

Comment: If I look at that link and follow link in page I get to http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2922223 which has downloads for 2008 r2 sp1.

Comment: You are right Paul Haldane. Missed that link on the page, was expecting it in the Hotfix page. Thank you!

Comment: Did the correct hotfix solve the problem, or do we have to wait until New Years 2018 to find out?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Server 2008R2 / Win7 downloads for this issue can be found at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2922223